# Python, print string on the same line for screen output

Tags: python-3.x, variables, printing, output, screen

I am lost on printing a character on the same line.

For example

```
 card = "--Diamonds--"
```

Output needed: --Diamonds--  --Diamonds--  --Diamonds--  --Diamonds--  --Diamonds--

The same string variable (not a list) to be repeated on a single line.
I don't want it to be a list at this stage, just an image for visuals.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

you could try to do it like this:

```
print(card*5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
card = "--Diamonds--"

print(card, card, card, card, card)
```

You can repeat it infitely just alway make a comma and then the variable

Answer (score 2):

This also works:

```py
    card = "--Diamonds--"
    for i in range(1, 6):
        print(card, end=' ')
```

This would output:

```
--Diamonds-- --Diamonds-- --Diamonds-- --Diamonds-- --Diamonds--
```

If you want there to be no spaces in between the words, you need to use:

```py
    card = "--Diamonds--"
    for i in range(1, 6):
        print(card, end='')
```

output:

```
--Diamonds----Diamonds----Diamonds----Diamonds----Diamonds--
```

Comment: If no spaces needed between, then, there is no need to use `for` loop, just `card*5` will be enough

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this with a new line, over six lines in printed a square (a card), I made a function that used list indexing to change the cards suite and rank, so I replaced range() with a list.

Answer (score 1):

As a possible answer:

```
card = "--Diamonds--"
result = card + card + card + card + card
print(result)
```